# Twython - Twitter search for 'vine.co' shooting blanks

Tags: api, twitter, twython, vine

I've been working happily away on a web-app that uses Twython and grabbing Vine's from twitter API using a search for vine.co in the tweets. Search has been working fine.

Suddenly, just in last day or two, searches for 'vine.co' returns blanks most of the time, yet searches for all sorts of other terms are working fine.

a search:

```
twythonObj.search(q='vine.co',count=3)
```

returns:

```
{u'search_metadata': {u'count': 3, u'completed_in': 0.036, u'max_id_str': u'34268106234236575', u'since_id_str': u'0', u'refresh_url': u'?since_id=3426810623425676&q=vine.co&include_entities=1', u'since_id': 0, u'query': u'vine.co', u'max_id': 3426810682342567}, u'statuses': []}
```

while a search for any other common word turns up lots. I won't dump the huge reply here for brevity.

I see there was Twitter API v1 blackout testing a week ago. Surely that would kill all searches if it were affecting Twython (ASIDE - I need to dig into Twython to understand how API changes affect current version).

Is anyone aware of Twitter purposely blocking vine.co searches on the API?  Not sure why that would be, but hoping someone has insight here. I'm a bit at a loss.

Comment: Found that Twitter API is having problems with low count searches.  Based on my testing it appears that search string affects this too - but for now a work-around is to use a higher count: Seems like 25 plus works reliably, but lower does not.   [link](https://dev.twitter.com/issues/1072)

Answer (score 0):

Twython actually allows the user to pass the API version they want to use, by default we are using the latest (1.1) Also, if there are any new functions that we haven't added to endpoints.py that Twitter releases.. you can still make use of those methods by:

```
from twython import Twython
t = Twython(auth stuff here)
t.get(url_to_new_method, params={'someparam': 'somevalue}) // or t.post for POSTs
```

:)